# Select multiple words in text box like block selection

Tags: c#, winforms

It is possible to select block of text in text box?

if i have text

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

I want to select :

```
 bc
 fg
 jk
```

But only possible is to select

```
 bc
efgh
ijk
```

I find start index( from where i want to selection start) length , last index(possiton character i want to go)  , line in witch are first and last index, but i cannot find way to override select method and select only block.

It is possible to override it?

Thnx

Comment: abcdefghijkl is a single string ?

Comment: Yes, it is some random text in textbox.

Comment: I think OP wants to do selects like one can do while selecting from command line window, or like ATL + select in Notepad++.

Comment: Depends on the textbox — WPF, WinForms, Web? Built-in only or third party?

Comment: @Andrey it is WinForms, i am still little noob with this all, because that i not use some third party components , i want first to learn to use built in components on right way...

Comment: No way. You could write your own if you could, but the regular TextBox can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, standard TextBox in Windows Forms does not support this kind of selection.
You may have better luck with a custom control (but I do not know which ones support it).